# UITableViewGrouped Section ~ Weird White Line below the TableView (WITH IMAGES)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

Please refer to the image.

If I use

```
    [self.tableView initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320) 
               style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

There is this small **WHITE Line** below the tableView Section. I thought is was a bug in the app, but it turns out that a lot of apps have this on them and some of them have this corrected.

How do I get rid of that white line ?

(The screen shot is an image of a `section` and I have set the background of `UIView` and `tableView` as green so that the line is clearly visible).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the tableView's `separatorStyle` property to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`. That looks a lot like what happens when `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched` is set instead, perhaps in a nib.

Comment: Glad to help! This one annoyed me for awhile last year, glad to spare you the headache. :D